# Is there any way to restrict TDengine only use TCP when inserting data?

Tags: tdengine

TDengine use both udp and tcp when inserting data, but there is a problem that when it uses udp, there could be a data loss issue.
I checked the /etc/taos/taos.cfg configuration file, there is no option for TCP, is there any way to restrict TDengine only use TCP to transport data?

Answer (score 1):

Since TDengine ver-2.1.0.1, there is a parameter called "rpcForceTcp" which you can set to 1 in taos.cfg otherwise it will transfer small data using UDP.